# Finding $\int \sec ^4(x)~\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \sec ^4(x) ~\mathrm dx$

I did this in two ways:

1)

\begin{align}
\int\sec^4(x) ~\mathrm dx
& = \int \sec^2(x)\sec^2(x) ~\mathrm dx \\
& = \sec^2(x)\tan(x) - 2\int \sec(x) \tan(x) \sec(x) \tan(x) ~\mathrm dx \\
& = \sec^2(x) \tan(x) - 2 \int \sec^2(x) (\sec^2(x)-1) ~\mathrm dx \\
& = \int \sec^4(x) ~\mathrm dx \\
& = \sec^2(x)\tan(x)-2\int \sec^4(x) ~\mathrm dx +2\int\sec^2(x) ~\mathrm dx \\
& = \int \sec^4(x) ~\mathrm dx \\
& = \frac{\sec^2(x)\tan(x)}{3}+2\tan(x) / 3 +C
\end{align}

2)
\begin{align}
\int \sec^4(x) ~\mathrm dx
& = \int (\tan^2(x)+1)^2 ~\mathrm dx \\
& = \int \tan^4(x) + 2\tan^2(x) +1 ~\mathrm dx \\
& = \int \tan^4(x) ~\mathrm dx +2\int \tan^2(x) ~\mathrm dx + x \\
& = (...) \\
& = \frac{\tan^3(x)}{3}-\tan(x)
\end{align}

So... which one is wrong( or both?)

Comment: Why not $$(\tan ^2x+1)\sec^2x$$

Comment: The second one is wrong, please give a detail derivation process.

Comment: Simply put, the steps are very unclear, some steps are completely omitted, etc. Make your steps clearer if you want feedback on your approaches to the problem.